# Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists()

Tags: php, arrays

I want to modify array of samples&lables and then pass to the predict() function. I must to do this because I want to get samples and labels from other.xls file and store in array so they can fit in this code.
This is the original code:

```
    $samples = [[5, 1, 1], [1, 5, 1], [1, 1, 5]];// is this array() form?
    $labels = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    $classifier = new NaiveBayes();
    $classifier->train($samples, $labels); 
    $classifier->predict([3, 1, 1]) //return a

    //other file.php
    predict(array $sample){
    $predictions = [];
    foreach ($this->targets as $index => $label) {
        $predictions[$label] = 0;
        foreach ($sample as $token => $count) {
            if (array_key_exists($token, $this->samples[$index])) {
                $predictions[$label] += $count * $this->samples[$index][$token];
            }
        }

     }
```

Then I modified the code to:

```
    $samples = array("samples1","samples2", "samples3",...,"samplesN");
    $labels = array("a","c","b");
```

but this get me error :

> Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in

Just curious what kind of array [[...]] is this? Is that same with normal array(..)?
Can somebody help me? I'm sure that I was wrong to remake the array

Comment: It seems that $sample in the second foreach should be $samples.

Comment: @PEMapModder ups sorry edited in question :')

Comment: `[]` is the shorthand for `array()`. Nothing more, nothing less.